# Reading file starting at a specific line into a vector of pairs

Tags: c++, vector, ifstream, getline

Here is a txt file snippet that I have which lists temperature, voltage, and sensitivity

```
Temp.      Voltage    Sensitivity
(Kelvin)   (Volts)    (milliVolts/Kelvin)

1.4     1.644290        -12.5
1.5     1.642990        -13.6
1.6     1.641570        -14.8
1.7     1.640030        -16.0
1.8     1.638370        -17.1
```

What I am trying to accomplish is reading the values for Temp and Voltage into a vector of pairs, so that if looked up the Temp, I can find the corresponding Voltage. Would it be easier/more efficient to make two separate vectors and just look up the corresponding value based on its position?

```
void Convert::readFile()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    vector<double> temp,voltage;
    double kelvin,mV;

    inFile.open("DT-670.txt");
    if (inFile) {
        cout << "File Open";

        while(inFile>>kelvin && inFile>> mV)
        {
            temp.push_back(kelvin);
            voltage.push_back(mV);
        }

        cout<<temp.size();

    }
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to [*map*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) one value to another...

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question

Comment: Your out of sync because you don't read the `Sensitivity`.  You need to read it; but you can ignore the value (not use it).

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ compare floating point equality".  Mapping and searching requiring comparing for equal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example code, you can change the line number and include conditional execution

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  ifstream file("data.txt");
  string str = "";
  string::size_type sz;

  uint32_t line_number = 4;

  while (std::getline(file, str)) {
    cout << str << endl;

    istringstream buf(str);
    istream_iterator<string> beg(buf), end;

    vector<string> tokens(beg, end);

    for (auto &s : tokens)
      cout << atof(s.c_str()) << " " << flush;

    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of just dumping code, _explain_ your solution.

Comment: Also, that's a remarkably inefficient way to tokenize lines.

Comment: Also, why use `atof` if you already have everything in a stringstream?

Comment: Also, why all the flushing?

Comment: Also, a space character is just that - one character. So, `" "` can be `' '`.

Comment: Also, `str` doesn't need that redundant initializer.

Comment: Also, `line_number` should be `const`.

Comment: Also, you never used `sz`.

Comment: Also, `line_number` is not used.  You can get rid of it.

Comment: You should check if the file open failed or succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to use the sensitivity data, you could do something like this:

```
std::map<double, double> table;
//...
double temperature = 0.0;
double voltage = 0.0;
double sensitivity = 0.0;
while (file >> temperature >> voltage >> sensitivity)
{
  table[temp] = voltage;
}
```

There is an fundamental issue here of using a floating point value as the search key.  Floating point values, by their internal representation, can't be represented exactly; thus `operator==` may not work correctly for all values.

To get around the equality issue, most programs use an equivalence or *epsilon* to determine equality.  For example, if the difference between two floating point values is less than 1E-6, consider them equal.  I recommend exploring `std::map` to see how to overload the comparison operator (or provide a function for comparing values).